# Why is ModelFragment.deliverModel() synchronized in CommonsWare 4.7 turorial #12?

Tags: android, commonsware

I'm working my way though version 4.7 of the CommonsWare master book.  I'm up to tutorial #12.  My question relates to the `deliverModel()` method in `ModelFragment`.  Why is it synchronized?

My confusion comes from my understanding that that method (`deliverModel()`) should already be only called from the UI thread.  It's called from a fragment `onActivityCreated()` and an `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute()`.

Thank you, Lee

Comment: You synchronize objects in order to make sure that only one thread at the time gets to be funky with the data. I didn't have opportunity to see this to tutorial to tell you what is the reason for this in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it synchronized?

For no good reason, apparently. I am sure that I had a reason once upon a time, but you are correct -- it is only invoked on the main application thread at present. I will remove the `synchronized` keyword sometime in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much Mark.  I was hoping you'd say something like that.  It looks like that method was refactored at some point which is how the synchronized was left in.  I am assuming that that is also why it looks like there is an extra 'contents == null' left over in the else section.  Doesn't matter really, that's small potatoes compared to my issue with the synchronized.